# Cleaning binary data frame

Tags: r, for-loop

Hi I am preping my dataset using for loop and ran into problem because of NA in the datase. the sample of my dataset is below

```
day1 <- c(0,0,0,1)
day2<- c(0,0,0,0)
day3<- c(1,1,0,0)
day4<- c(0,0,1,0)
day5<- c(0,NA,NA,1)
day6<-c(1,NA,NA,1)
day7<-c(1,NA,NA,1)
df<- data.frame(day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7)
```

The resulting data should not have 1 and followed by 0 on the next day instead once it the row has 1 and the following column followed the condition, the entire column starting from that 1 should be all 1 (except NA). thus, i fix it following this condition. i looked at the first 1 in each row as an index 1 and if there is more 1 than zero (or exactly as much as zero) in the following column combined, i changed all zero to 1 frmom that index 1. if there is more zero than one, then the index 1 become zero. using the following code

```
a = df[1,]
for (index in seq_along(a)){
  element=a[index]
  if (element == 1) {
    sum = sum(a[index:length(a)])
    new_vector =a[index:length(a)]
    print(length(new_vector)/2)
    if (sum < length(new_vector)/2) {
      a[index] = c(0)
    }
    else {
      a[index:(index+length(new_vector)-1)]= c(1)
    }
  }
}
print(a)
```

Error occur when i include rows with NA. i want to run this on row with NA too but keep NA there so ideally i would get

```
day1 <- c(0,0,0,0)
day2<- c(0,0,0,0)
day3<- c(1,1,0,0)
day4<- c(1,1,1,0)
day5<- c(1,NA,NA,1)
day6<-c(1,NA,NA,1)
day7<-c(1,NA,NA,1)
df<- data.frame(day1,day2,day3,day4,day5,day6,day7)
df
```

i tried with (seq_along(a),!is.na)
as well as use first if condition to only include non-NA row but it gaves errors and just skip the entire loop
please help thank so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to restructure your data into tidy format instead of wide, you can compose existing R functions to solve the problem instead of writing imperative code. Without spending too much time trying to understand the algorithm you described (my day 4 values are different from your expected results), here's the idea.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
day1 <- c(0,0,0,1)
day2<- c(0,0,0,0)
day3<- c(1,1,0,0)
day4<- c(0,0,1,0)
day5<- c(1,NA,NA,1)
df<- data.frame(row.id = 1:4, day1,day2,day3,day4,day5)

df2 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = 'day1':'day5',
                    names_to = 'day',
                    values_to = 'value')


df2 %>% group_by(row.id) %>%
    arrange(day, row.id) %>%
    group_by(day) %>%
    mutate(lag.value = lag(value),
           new.value = ifelse(!is.na(value) &
                                !is.na(lag.value) &
                                value == 1 &
                                lag.value == 0,
                              0, value)) 

   row.id day   value lag.value new.value
    <int> <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1      1 day1      0        NA         0
 2      2 day1      0         0         0
 3      3 day1      0         0         0
 4      4 day1      1         0         0
 5      1 day2      0        NA         0
 6      2 day2      0         0         0
 7      3 day2      0         0         0
 8      4 day2      0         0         0
 9      1 day3      1        NA         1
10      2 day3      1         1         1
11      3 day3      0         1         0
12      4 day3      0         0         0
13      1 day4      0        NA         0
14      2 day4      0         0         0
15      3 day4      1         0         0
16      4 day4      0         1         0
17      1 day5      1        NA         1
18      2 day5     NA         1        NA
19      3 day5     NA        NA        NA
20      4 day5      1        NA         1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to add another `if` statement in the scope of the first one, that is true when there is `NA` and performs the actions you want.

So something like this:

```
if (element == 1) {
   blah blah}
if (is.na(element)) {
   change nothing or change something
}
```

Comment: Thank you both! I tried before is (element == "NA) {next}. and also  is.na. at the end of the loop after else() and also tried in the beginning but other condition then did not work

Comment: @KonradRudolph that is indeed correct. Let me edit my answer. Thanks

Comment: @dnatcha Please accept an answer if you think it solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much. i followed @Henrik. instruction using rle. his suggestion is the following

```
setDT(a)
# create row index
a[ , ri := .I]
# convert to long format
d = melt(a, id.var = "ri")  
d2 = d[ , {
  # calculate run lengths
  r = rle(value)
  r$values[
# when preceeding values is 1 and...
c(NA, head(r$values, -1)) == 1 &
# focal value is 0 and its run length is 1 and...
             r$values == 0 & r$lengths == 1 & 
# following value is 1 or NA, set value to 1
             c(tail(r$values, -1), NA) %in% c(1, NA)] = 1
# when focal value is 1 and...
  r$values[r$values == 1 &
# following value is zero and...             
             c(tail(r$values, -1), NA) == 0 &
# its run length is > 1, set value to 0
             c(tail(r$lengths, -1), NA) > 1] = 0
# reconstruct values from the runs  
  inverse.rle(r)},
# do the above for each (original) row, i.e. the row index ri
  by = ri]
df<-dcast(d2, ri ~ rowid(ri))
print(df)
```

at first i still have some problem because some rows have more than one 0 between 1. and i fixed it by changing r$length >4 in

```
r$values == 0 & r$lengths <4 &
```